# Angular UI-Grid expandableRow selectionChange update parent

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I use Angular-UI Grid and the ui-grid-expandable option. 
Is there an option to also select the parent grid row if one row of the expandable(child) grid is selected?
If not at least I need access to the parent grid/row in the rowSelectionChanged event of the sub-(expandable) grid, it seems not to have an own scope?

```
 gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope, function (rows) {
             var selectedRows=gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows();
             ...
             //select parent grid row here...
              });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there's a way to do it. You just have to walk backwards up the scope to access the parent row and the parent row's grid api. Remember that `appScope` always references the parent scope of the grid. So in your expandable child grid that parent scope contains the row object.

In your child grid's `onRegisterApi` handler you can access the parent row via: `row.grid.appScope.row`. Then you can select the parent row with: `row.grid.appScope.row.grid.api.selection.selectRow(row.grid.appScope.row.entity)`

Here's a code example that cleans it up a bit:

```
onRegisterApi: function (api) {
  api.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope, function (row, event) {
    var parentRow = row.grid.appScope.row;
    if (api.selection.getSelectedRows().length > 0) {
      parentRow.grid.api.selection.selectRow(parentRow.entity);
    }
    else {
      parentRow.grid.api.selection.unSelectRow(parentRow.entity);
    }
  });
}
```

And a demo plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/7HFHPTtmcXvgoJCKiRTd?p=preview

Comment: a related question that just came up: what is the solution to the opposite use case, I want to unselect child/expanded row selections when the parent row is unselected?

Comment: Sorry for the wait; been away. You'd need to register the child grid somehow with the parent row, which you could hack up in the child selection handler. Then add a selection handler in the parent to call `clearSelectedRows()` in the child api when the parent row is de-selected: http://plnkr.co/edit/gpii2bixGvgTyBLxtS1M?p=preview